# Spice Simulation including Verilog model

Tags: circuit-analysis, verilog, simulation, spice

I would like to include a magnetic tunnel junction in a circuit and simulate it. Since LTspice does not have this device, I decided to model it in Verilog.

Now, I am not able to include the MTJ model (Verilog file .v) in the LTspice. Do you have any suggestion? I have surfed the net for hours but I do not manage. I have a MAC.

Comment: Exactly what kind of MTJ behavior are you trying to model in SPICE? What does the Verilog model do that you haven't been able to do with a SPICE model?

Comment: My supervisor gave me a code that I could not understand, so I decided to simulate the circuit in Matlab. Anyway I would need to simulate a tunnel barrier, so the tunnel resistance depends on the voltage. The material will be MgO. Do you have any idea/solution? thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Varilog is typically used to model *digital systems.* Your magnetic tunnel junction, as well as your simulator, are *analog systems.* Are you sure you know what you're doing?

In any case, there already exists spice models for magnetic tunnel junction devices.

Here is a link: http://mtj.umn.edu/Downloads.html

Comment: I already tried those, but do not work to me. Moreover, I would like to include a tunnel junction in a circuit..

Comment: Those files should very much be component descriptions that you use to make modules that you add to your simulated circuit. That is the usual reason for making such files, and making them public. If there is more to them, then you will probably have to look at the source and pick out the parts than interest you.

Comment: "Our self-contatined, physics-based magnetic tunnel junction (MTJ) SPICE model" Yeah... doesn't get any more obvious than this. Those are component models for magnetic tunnel junction devices.

Comment: I am very bad, I do not manage. Could you help me please if I share the screen (with compensation? If yes, you could write me down on mickey.martini@icloud.com

Comment: I must respectfully decline. It's is almost for sure against SE guidelines to do a screen share. I recommend learning more about SPICE, and, in particular LTspcie, and how to add external models.

Comment: I meant using Skype..btw feel free :) you can contact me by mail, otherwise thanks a lot for you help anyway!